# Is there a way in for loop to pass in more than 1 argument to iterate over for running a python script?

Tags: bash, shell

In Bash/Shell are we able to iterate over multiple arguments in a for loop and run the same command for each argument? For example able to get the first value of the service and get the first value of the config and run the python script/command against the ip provided. Then get the second value of the service and get the second value of the config and run the python script/command against the ip provided?

```
#!/bin/bash 
args=() 
while getopts ':d:t:' opt ; do 
  case $opt in 
      d) args+=( -d "$OPTARG" ) ;; 
      t) args+=( -t "$OPTARG" ) ;;
      ?) echo "Invalid option $OPTARG" ;; 
      :) echo "Option $OPTARG needs an argument" ;; 
  esac 
done 

shift $(( OPTIND - 1 )) 
list=(service config_file) 

for "${list[@]}" in "$@" ; do 
 python /scripts/service.py "${args[@]}" "{list[1]}" "{list[2]}"
done
```

example invocation:

```
/users/scripts/serviceTest.sh -s Test1080 Test720 -c /config/1080/config.xml /config/720/config.xml -d "7.0.0" -t "Start" 17.15.26.12
```

Tried list but seeing the error unrecognized arguments. Expecting to be able to iterate over multiple arguments and run the python script/command.

Comment: "Not quite like the way I described" isn't telling us what it _is_ doing -- thus, isn't describing a specific problem in enough detail to allow a solution. (Consider using `set -x` / `bash -x yourscript` to get trace-level logging, if that helps provide a better understanding of what's going wrong and how it differs from expected behavior).

Comment: BTW, while it may or may not be relevant (as described above, I don't understand your problem), [BashFAQ #35](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) has a more generic argument-handling workflow than what getopts gives you.

Comment: BTW, why would you run `for ip in service config_file` (insofar as those are the exact two values that `"${list[@]}"` expands to)? -- and note that it _should_ be `"${list[@]}"`, _with the quotes_. Anyhow -- assuming the variable names are expected to mean something, `service` doesn't make sense for `$ip`.

Comment: Personally, I would define each service/config pair with a separate use of a single option, e.g. `servertest.sh -sc Test1080 /config/1080/config.xml -sc Test720 /config/720/config.xml`. But `getopts` does not support multiple arguments per option; you would have to process `$@` yourself.

Comment: @chepner the python script will not recognize -sc it processes -s -c as separate parameters.

Comment: `${list[@]}` is not an "lvalue"; the thing after `for` has to be something you can assign to. (`for x in ...`, `for list[0] in ...`, etc, though you virtually  never see this kind of array assignment in a loop.)

Comment: @arthi That's not an option for the python sciprt; it's an option for the shell script. And no, `getopts` doesn't support multi character option names,  but changing the option to something like `-x` doesn't affect my point.

Comment: Among other things, you're missing the leading `$`s in the last 2 args of `python /scripts/service.py "${args[@]}" "{list[1]}" "{list[2]}"`. Also bash arrays start at `0` not `1`.

Comment: Have you considered using Python instead? [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) lets you pass [multiple arguments per option](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs), then you'd just have to `zip` them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to pass your service/config information as a sequence of alternating positional arguments

```
serviceTest.sh -d "7.0.0" -t "Start" 17.15.26.12 Test1080 /config/1080/config.xml Test720 /config/720/config.xml
```

Your script would consume them using a `while` loop that explicit shifts a pair out of the arguments as you go.

```
#!/bin/bash 
args=() 
while getopts ':d:t:' opt ; do 
  case $opt in 
      d) args+=( -d "$OPTARG" ) ;; 
      t) args+=( -t "$OPTARG" ) ;;
      \?) echo "Invalid option $OPTARG" ;; 
      :) echo "Option $OPTARG needs an argument" ;; 
  esac 
done 

shift $(( OPTIND - 1 )) 

 
# Not sure what you are doing with this, but pull it off
# before you start iterating over service/config pairs
address=$1
shift

while (($# > 0)); do
    service=$1
    config=$2
    python /scripts/service.py "${args[@]}" "$service" "$config"
    shift 2
done
```

Comment: The `?` (question mark) in `case` must be escaped or the last case will never execute.

Comment: ((: #$ > 0: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "#$ > 0") issuing error.

Comment: :facepalm: Should be `$#`.